# Knockout applyBindings does not applyBinding

Tags: json, knockout.js

I have just started to use `knockout.js` and am stuck when trying to show JSON data.

**My HTML is**

```html
<p>Dealer Location: <input id="dealerlocation" data-bind="value: DealerLocation" /></p>
<p>Contact Report Date: <input id="crdate" data-bind="value: CRDate" /></p>
```

**My Script Block is**

```
function viewAction() {
    var self = this;
    self.DealerLocation = ko.observable("");
    self.CRDate = ko.observable("");
};

var viewActionModel = new viewAction();

function GetActionByID() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ws/someservice.asmx/GetAction",
        data: "{pacid: '" + $('input[id$=hidActionID]').val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
                var action = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;
                $.each(action, function (index, axn) {                        
                    viewActionModel.DealerLocation = axn.DealerLocation;
                    viewActionModel.CRDate = axn.CRDate;                        
                });
            }
        });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    GetActionByID();
    //alert(viewActionModel.DealerLocation);
    ko.applyBindings(viewActionModel);
});
```

Note: If I uncomment alert then applyBinding works otherwise it does not.

What is missing here???

Ragards.

Answer (score 2):

This is a wrong way to assign observables.

```
viewActionModel.DealerLocation = axn.DealerLocation;
viewActionModel.CRDate = axn.CRDate;
```

Do it like this.

```
viewActionModel.DealerLocation(axn.DealerLocation);
viewActionModel.CRDate(axn.CRDate);
```

By doing what you do now you are replacing observables with regular variable. It was working with alert because this replacement took place before binding and knockout just picked up your regular variables. Read more about observables.

Comment: It works perfectly now! But why it was working with the wrong assignment when Alert() was placed there?

Comment: Thanks; definitely that is a must for me.